# PHP - Parent method not recognized in child class

Tags: php

I'm learning OOP and I'm trying to Insert a query in a database (MySQL), the issue is when I try to call the Class Connection to make a prepare statement it gives me a error.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening? Thanks.

DbConn.php (parent class)

```
<?php 

class DbConn {
    private $host = 'locahost';
    private $dbname = 'gawker';
    private $dbusername = 'root';
    private $dbpassword = '';

    public function connect(){
        try {

            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . '; dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';' . $this->dbusername . ',' . $this->dbpassword);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            return $pdo;


        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'Unbale to connect to the database server: ' . $e->getMessage() . 'in ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

AddArtile.php (cild class)

```
<?php 

include __DIR__ . '/../includes/DbConn.php';


class AddArticle extends DbConn {

    public function insertArticle($title, $content) {

        
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO articles (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content);';


        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $values = [
            'title' => $title,
            'content' => $content
        ];

        $stmt->execute($values);
        
    }
}

?>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
> string in C:\xampp\htdocs\gawker\includes\AddArticle.php:14
> Stack
> trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gawker\public\addarticle.php(16):
> AddArticle->insertArticle('asdasd', 'asdasdasd')
> #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\gawker\includes\AddArticle.php on line 14

Comment: Your `connect()` method is returning a string (the error message returned by the method).

Comment: Do not let `AddArticle` extend from `DbConn`. A "AddArticle" is not a database connection.

Comment: Why is your `connect()` method returning a string when a `PDOException` is caught? Why not let the exception bubble up so the caller can handle the situation?

Comment: @Progman Hello, thanks for your reply! What do you mean by bubble up?

Comment: @D1__1 Thanks for the reply! Does that mean that the connection is not going through? right?

Comment: `connect()` does not return a valid PDO object.

Comment: @J.Reis When an exception is thrown, it goes up the call chain (like function or method calls) to whoever is using a `catch()` block to handle the exception. If there is no such `catch()` block, the PHP script itself will exit/die. The `connect()` method might not be the right place to handle a `PDOException`, instead your code might/should handle the `PDOException`. Currently you catch the exception and return a string with the error message instead. But you are not checking if `connect()` is returning a `PDO` object or a string. Instead you just assume a connection was successful.

Comment: If you are just learning PHP - try get used to adding the type hints (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) this may help understand what you are returning and when you break it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not following the proper PDO __construct when initializing it.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

```
PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . '; dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';' . $this->dbusername . ',' . $this->dbpassword)
```

You are trying to pass 1 parameter, when the construct takes 3.

The parameters should be formatted like so:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbusername, $this->dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $pdo;
```

Also for classes, you should try to use namespaces instead of include/require.